# summarise vs. summarise_each function in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to summarise the value for one variable after splitting the data with group_by using dplyr package, the following code works fine and the output is listed below, but I can not substitute `summarise_each` with `summriase` even only one column need to be calculated, I wonder why?

```
   iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% select(one_of('Sepal.Length')) %>%
                       summarise_each(funs(mean(.)))
```

or I will get the output like "S3:lazy".

Comment: What is your expected output?  Using your code, I get `Species.Length` as the 2nd column name.  Is this to change the column name?

Comment: with my code, I can get the mean value of Sepal.Length according to factor Species.

Comment: Yes, you can get that, but I didn't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

`summarize` and `summarize_each` work quite differently. `summarize` is in fact simpler — just specify the expression directly:

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    select(Sepal.Length) %>%
    summarize(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

You can choose any name for the output column, it doesn’t need to be the same as the input.

Comment: Noted, the verb summarize doesn't have `funs`.